# warning: initialisation from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c

Hi all it's been sometime since I've touched C so I'm really rusty on it.  I wrote a small program to create a matrix using two dynamic arrays.  However, I'm getting this warning and I don't understand why?  I guess I'm not quite sure about pointers to pointers.  Can someone help me point out where my problem is?  Thanks.

```
sm.c: In function ‘main’:
sm.c:11:13: warning: initialisation from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
sm.c: In function ‘makeMatrix’:
sm.c:27:3: warning: return from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int (**intptr) (); 
intptr makeMatrix(int n); 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  int n = 2;  

  int **A = makeMatrix(n);
  if(A) { 
    printf("A\n");
  }
  else printf("ERROR");
}

intptr makeMatrix(int size) {
  int **a = malloc(sizeof *a * size);
  if (a) 
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {   
      a[i] = malloc(sizeof *a[i] * size);
    }   
  }
  return a;
}
```

Comment: What is the `()` doing in the `intptr` `typedef`?!

Comment: [Stack Overflow is Not a Syntax Checker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128596/172496)

Comment: Lucky for him this is syntactically fine.

Comment: I guess the question is, what did you think `typedef int (**intptr) (); ` meant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got some problems here:

```
typedef int (**intptr) (); 
intptr makeMatrix(int n); 

...

int **A = makeMatrix(n);
```

The `intptr` typedef declares a pointer to a pointer to a function that takes an indeterminate number of arguments and returns an `int`.  `A` is not an `int`.

You need to write:

```
int **makeMatrix(int n);


int **A = makeMatrix(n);
```

Using a `typedef` won't help much here.

```
typedef int **(*intptr)();
```

That declares a pointer to a function that returns a pointer to a pointer to an `int`.  But writing

```
intptr makeMatrix(int n);
```

would declare that `makeMatrix()` returns a pointer to a function, not an `int **`.

Answer (score 0):

Your typedef has an extra `()`, making it a zero argument function type.  Remove that and you should be good.